# Help with the system of 13 equations

Tags: periodic-functions

Homework from electronics class, but since it looks like a math problem to me i decided to look for help here.

I am given this composite periodic signal that has 6 harmonics:

$$V(t)=V_0+\sum_{k=1}^6V_k\;cos(k\ \omega t+\phi_k)$$

I also have a table of 13 values for $V(t)$ that correspond to 13 moments in time ($t$) during one period of the signal.
From the table i am easily able to find the value of $\ \omega$.

But i also need to determine amplitude($V_k$) and phase($\phi_k$) of each individual harmonic(that's 12 variables) as well as the offset ($V_0$).

So from the table i am able to form 13 equations with 13 variables(unknowns) that look like, for example:

$$19,714=V_0+\sum_{k=1}^6V_k\;cos(\phi_k)\\
-13,15=V_0+\sum_{k=1}^6V_k\;cos(k \frac {2\pi}{13}+\phi_k)\\
0,1716=V_0+\sum_{k=1}^6V_k\;cos(k \frac {4\pi}{13}+\phi_k)\\
...\\
-4,851=V_0+\sum_{k=1}^6V_k\;cos(k \frac {24\pi}{13}+\phi_k)
$$

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93RQv.jpg) is the full list of equations for those that are interested:
[image: Equations]

I realize that i probably should expand the sums and start eliminating variables somehow but the problem is i don't even know where to start.What is the easiest/fastest way to solve this?

Comment: As far as I can see, you only have 8 unknowns (the 7 V's and phi). Am I wrong ?

Comment: i have 7 V's(V0,V1,V2...V6) and 6 Phi's(phi1,ph2...phi6)

Comment: Sorry for that : I missed the index for the phi's.

Comment: I do not see the benefit of doing this by hand. Maybe use something like mathematica

Comment: It's non-linear and small, so my first thought would be to use a Nelder-Mead simplex search.